# Need to fill data frame with missing years and value in 2nd column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frames with counts from a series of years, 1970-2020, generated by a `subset` command from a larger data set, i.e. resulting in two columns "Year" and "Count":

```
Year         Count
1987         8
1989         1
1991         1
1992         4
1995         11
1996         3
1997         7
.
.
.
2019         2
2020         5
```

There are missing years where Count=0, and I need a procedure to fill these df's with the missing years and Count=0. I have this script that I can't get to work:

```
library(tidyr)
aug <- subset(mainframe, month==8)
complete(aug, year = 1987:2020, fill = list(Count = 0))
```

Here's a sample dataframe 'aug':

```
dput(aug)
structure(list(month = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), year = structure(1:28, .Label = c("1987", 
"1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", 
"1996", "1998", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2013", "2015", 
"2016", "2018", "2020"), class = "factor"), Count = c(4L, 0L, 
3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(8L, 20L, 
32L, 44L, 56L, 68L, 80L, 92L, 104L, 116L, 128L, 140L, 152L, 164L, 
176L, 188L, 200L, 212L, 224L, 236L, 248L, 260L, 272L, 284L, 296L, 
308L, 320L, 332L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your sample dataframe seems to be already your expected output.

Comment: that said, `complete(aug, year, fill = list(Count = 0, month = 8))` should work. You don't need to specify what the year variable will be in this case, `complete` automatically fills in between.

Comment: Doing this I still have the incomplete list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, you want to have a complete dataframe containing year 1987 to 2020, but there are some missing years in your `aug` dataframe, and you want to fill in the missing years with `month = "8"` and `Count = 0`.

Here's a `tidyverse` approach (in your original `aug` dataframe, your `year` is `factor`, so at the end of my solution I also transformed it into `factor`):

### Your dataset

```
    month year Count
8       8 1987     4
20      8 1988     0
32      8 1989     3
44      8 1990     3
56      8 1991     0
68      8 1992     0
80      8 1993     1
92      8 1994     0
104     8 1995     1
116     8 1996     1
128     8 1998     3
140     8 2000     0
152     8 2001     0
164     8 2002     0
176     8 2003     0
188     8 2004     2
200     8 2005     0
212     8 2006     0
224     8 2007     0
236     8 2008     2
248     8 2009     0
260     8 2010     1
272     8 2011     1
284     8 2013     0
296     8 2015     0
308     8 2016     1
320     8 2018     0
332     8 2020     1
```

### Solution

```
library(tidyverse)

aug %>% mutate(year = as.numeric(as.character(year))) %>% 
  complete(year = first(year):max(year), # or year = 1987:2020
           fill = list(month = "8", Count = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(year = as.factor(year))
```

### Output

```
year    month   Count
1987    8   4
1988    8   0
1989    8   3
1990    8   3
1991    8   0
1992    8   0
1993    8   1
1994    8   0
1995    8   1
1996    8   1
1997    8   0
1998    8   3
1999    8   0
2000    8   0
2001    8   0
2002    8   0
2003    8   0
2004    8   2
2005    8   0
2006    8   0
2007    8   0
2008    8   2
2009    8   0
2010    8   1
2011    8   1
2012    8   0
2013    8   0
2014    8   0
2015    8   0
2016    8   1
2017    8   0
2018    8   0
2019    8   0
2020    8   1
```

Comment: I don't understand as I still miss the missing years after this procedure.

Comment: See my edited answer which includes your input for your reference. For example you have missing records for year `1997` and `1999`, after my codes, `1997` and `1999` are filled with `month = "8"` and `Count = 0`. Make sure you saved the output of the codes like:  `aug <- aug %>% mutate(year = as.numeric(as.character(year))) %>% complete(year = first(year):max(year), fill = list(month = "8", Count = 0)) %>% mutate(year = as.factor(year))`